# Search items on database through Web Api and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I would like to pass a query parameter to a Controller in ASP.NET Core. Here are the two related methods:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Heroes")]
public class HeroesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [NoCache]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(_context.Heroes.ToArray());
    }

    [HttpGet("{searchTerm}", Name = "Search")]
    //GET: api/Heroes/?searchterm=
    public JsonResult Find(string searchTerm)
    {
        return new JsonResult(_context.Heroes.Where(h => hero.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).ToArray());
    }
}
```

When I type the url `/api/heroes` the method Get is called. But when I type `/api/heroes/?searchTerm=xxxxx` then the same Get method is called, like if there wasn't any parameter in the URL.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code you can try to do this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Heroes")]
public class HeroesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [NoCache]
    //GET: api/Heroes
    //GET: api/Heroes?searchTerm=
    public JsonResult Get(string searchTerm) //string is nullable, so it's good for optional parameters
    {
        if (searchTerm == null)
        {
        ...
        }
        else
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

You haven't to put query string parameters in the decorator because they are automatically mapped from methods parameters.